# set authorization header for susbsequent client requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking how I can set the "Authorization: Bearer ..." header for subsequent user requests.

Here for example I save my user to the database, generate a token, and send a welcome email with the token :

```
await user.save()
const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
sendWelcomeEmail(user.email, user.name, token)
res.status(201).send({ user, token })
```

Now that the user have the token, how can he use it in an "Authorization: Bearer..." header without having to set the header himself in the browser ?

So that I can then grab the token here :

```
const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
```

Comment: Headers will always have to be added. But something you could look into are **cookies**.

Comment: But how can I have the "Authorization" header added in the user's request ?

Comment: If you're using cookies, you use a slightly different mechanism. If you use cookies, then you're concerned with the `req.cookies`, not with the `req.header`. So you could set the cookie on `res.cookies.auth` for example and then check it on `req.cookies.auth` in the future.

Comment: Yes it would work. But I'm looking for a solution with the "Authorization" header instead.  When the user is authenticated, how can further requests include the "Authorization: Bearer..." header ?

Comment: You will unfortunately have to do it yourself.  But if you're using something like axios where you can set interceptors, it can help you accomplish that, but with headers you need to add them yourself.

Comment: I understand that the "Authorization: Bearer" is not to be used in the browser. Instead, it's only used from the backend.  Right ?

Comment: Headers are used both by a browser and a backend. But you’re correct the Authorization header is more interesting for the backend because it lets the backend know (if you’re using the authorization header as your mechanism) that the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you send the token plain in a mail the user always has to include it.

You can send the Authentification Header to the client by using

```
res.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token)
```

This should stay in the header until session is terminated

Comment: Yes, but how can I include the "Authorization" header in the user's request ?

Answer (score 0):

Computers don’t do magic Esther you add it or no one will do it.
One option is to set it on sessionStorage the token will be there as long as the tab in which you add it is not close if you close it it will be remove

Comment: But with sessionStorage, will the "Authorization" header be set ?     I'm trying to set that for the user (in the user's browser).